# Debug Content Security Policy (CSP) violations in Visual Studio

Tags: cordova, debugging, visual-studio-2017, content-security-policy

I am developing a Cordova UWP app in Visual Studio Professional.
During runtime, I can see CSP violations like this in the JavaScript console:

```
CSP14312: Resource violated directive 'script-src ms-appx: 'unsafe-eval'' in Host Defined Policy: inline script. Resource will be blocked.
```

How can I find the source of this violation? Visual Studio does not show which resource is the culprit.